# Enable on.click function for bxslider

Tags: javascript, bxslider

I need help with creating a js function that will enable the slides to move to the next one, when the user right-mouse-clicks anywhere within the slide/picture.

I'm using bxSlider.

Here's the JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/202/

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  auto: 'true',
  minSlides: 5,
  maxSlides: 5,
  touchEnabled: 'true',
  swipeThreshold: 50,
  speed: 1000,
  pause: 5000,
  preventDefaultSwipeX: 'true',
  preventDefaultSwipeY: 'true',
  keyboardEnabled: 'true',
  controls: false,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>
    <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>

<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```

Comment: By adding class to all of the images (.hero1), I came up with this but still without a proper result:
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slider img.hero1').on('click', function(){
  slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
      slider.goToNextSlide();
   });
  });
</script>